# reversing a regular expression

Tags: regex, perl, expression

I want to have the reverse complement of a DNA string in Perl. So that is simple enough and I have the following expression.

```
$revcomp =~ tr/ACGTacgt[]N/TGCAtgca][./;
```

followed by reversing the string. The `[]` take care of ambiguous characters. However, if I want to extend this to allow more complex expressions, this simple scheme fails. e.g., `C[AG]{7,10}[ACGT]{5,8}ATGC` will result in a regular expression `GCAT{8,5}[ACGT]{01,7}[CT]G` which is not what we want (after curly braces are also accounted for). The expected reverse complement for this would be `GCAT[ACGT]{5,8}[CT]{7,10}G`. How could I go about this?

Comment: Start by explain how you get `GCAT[ACGT]{5,8}[CT]{7,10}G` from `C[AG]{7,10}[ACGT]{5,8}ATGC`

Comment: Reverse complement of a DNA string is obtained by reversing the string followed by replacing A with T, C with G, G with C, and T with A. If we have a quantifier with a character, the same quantifier should be associated with the reverse complemented character as in Dave's answer below.

Comment: "Something should be associated with something" is not a description of how to do something. If you can't tell a person how to do it, how do you expect to tell a computer? (You're also wrong about wanting to reverse the string since your desired output doesn't have `01` in it. Your description of the algorithm is completely wrong.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the regexes with quantifiers to work correctly, you'll need to reverse the expression element-wise rather than character-wise.  By "element-wise", I mean that a single character or character class along with the following quantifier (if there is one) must be treated as a single unit.  e.g., In your example of `C[AG]{7,10}[ACGT]{5,8}ATGC`, there are 7 elements: C-[AG]{7,10}-[ACGT]{5,8}-A-T-G-C.  You need to break it down into that list of elements and reverse the order of the list rather than reversing it as a single string.

**ETA: Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $re = 'C[AG]{7,10}[ACGT]{5,8}ATGC';

$re =~ tr/ACGTacgt/TGCAtgca/;

my @elem = $re =~ /((?:\[.*?\]|.)(?:\{.*?})?)/g;

my $rev = join '', reverse @elem;

say $rev;
```

Output:

`GCAT[TGCA]{5,8}[TC]{7,10}G`